# Chaincode docker container not created on hyperledger fabric 2.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I have created hyperledger 2.2 setup on my machine using test-network by below step

1. used below command, in `/fabric-samples/test-network` directory and up container of `org1`, `org2` and `orderer` with respect to their CA.

```sh
./network.sh up createChannel -ca -c mychannel -s couchdb -i 2.2.0
```

2. Deploy chaincode on `mychannel` using

```
./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic1 -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go/ -ccl go
```

3. Created new channel as `channel1` and join this channel only `org1` first
4. Added new org as `org3` and joined to `channel1` using command

```
./addOrg3.sh up -ca -c channel1 -s couchdb -i 2.2.0
```

After that want to deploy chaicode on `channel1` however I when I used command to deploy chaincode it try to deploy chaincode on `org1` and `org2` which make it failed please anybody suggest me how to deploy chaincode on `channel1` on `org1` and `org3` only which joined to `channel1`.

```
./network.sh deployCC -c channel1 -ccn basic1 -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go/ -ccl go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./test-network/network.sh deployCC ...` calls `./test-network/scripts/deployCC.sh`

In this `deployCC.sh`, it is hardcoded to deploy the chaincode in `org1` and `org2`.

It works by changing from `org1 & org2` to `org1 & org3`

- ./test-network/scripts/deployCC.sh

```sh
...


## package the chaincode
packageChaincode

## Install chaincode on peer0.org1 and peer0.org3
infoln "Installing chaincode on peer0.org1..."
installChaincode 1
infoln "Install chaincode on peer0.org3..."
installChaincode 3

## query whether the chaincode is installed
queryInstalled 1

## approve the definition for org1
approveForMyOrg 1

## check whether the chaincode definition is ready to be committed
## expect org1 to have approved and org3 not to
checkCommitReadiness 1 "\"Org1MSP\": true" "\"Org3MSP\": false"
checkCommitReadiness 3 "\"Org1MSP\": true" "\"Org3MSP\": false"

## now approve also for org3
approveForMyOrg 3

## check whether the chaincode definition is ready to be committed
## expect them both to have approved
checkCommitReadiness 1 "\"Org1MSP\": true" "\"Org3MSP\": true"
checkCommitReadiness 3 "\"Org1MSP\": true" "\"Org3MSP\": true"

## now that we know for sure both orgs have approved, commit the definition
commitChaincodeDefinition 1 3

## query on both orgs to see that the definition committed successfully
queryCommitted 1
queryCommitted 3

## Invoke the chaincode - this does require that the chaincode have the 'initLedger'
## method defined
if [ "$CC_INIT_FCN" = "NA" ]; then
  infoln "Chaincode initialization is not required"
else
  chaincodeInvokeInit 1 3
fi

...
```

Comment: I would not recommend making too many changes like this to the test network scripts since that is not their intended purpose: “The network is meant to be used only as a tool for education and testing. It should not be used as a template for deploying a production network.”
The test network next steps should give you enough info for this sort of scenario https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploy_chaincode.html

Comment: @James Taylor Using the test network template in production I think I shouldn't do it either. However, I think it is rather recommended to learn the concept while testing the test network script by changing it. In particular, what I changed above is simply 7 lines excluding comments. If someone wants to learn to deploy chaincode for a new organization, they can refer to the above to quickly compare what to consider.

Comment: In my experience, when performing tutorials, I learned a lot by modifying the content as desired and executing it. If you only have to follow the guide's scenario as you said, I think that's rather the wrong attitude.

Comment: Experimenting with scenarios in a tutorial is a good way to learn what's going on however it is worth highlighting that there are downsides to making too many changes to test network scripts. There's certainly no harm making small edits to the scripts, as suggested, but they intentionally hide a lot of complexity and experimenting with different channel membership is an ideal point to move on to the next steps in the tutorial to learn about what's happening under the covers.

Comment: @James Taylor I haven't understood your comment yet. Following the question, I explained why and answered it to behave as I wanted. I think it's weird to answer the tutorial question assuming it is production.  Do I need to specify any problems that may arise from that behavior? Please tell me exactly which part to add and i will reflect it. I want to resolve your downvote.

Comment: It would help if there was some context in the answer, rather than just the script changes. I have tried to provide that in my answer and the comments above but essentially I wouldn't recommend going too far with editing the test network scripts without understanding the commands they're running. Expecting the deployCC to work in this scenario is probably an indication that the tutorial needs more work, which I'll feed back.

Comment: I've read your answers, and I understand what your intentions are.
But I think you have a poor reason to proceed with what you said.

If he asked about the process of deploying chaincode, I would have answered it in detail. However, the question of the questioner was that the deployCC command did not work for org3, and only minimally answered the features and modifications of deployCC.

Comment: depending on the question, I think the answer can be comprehensive. But `can be comprehensive` is different from `must be comprehensive`. I know what you mean, but I think the answer I wrote is good enough, I don't plan to revise it, and I don't think I can solve your downvote. sry

Comment: The questioner and answerer think it is ideal to provide more accurate minimal code to each other. I provided minimal code. I think the questioner should be studying how to deploy chaincode. Also, if he is curious or a problem arises, i think he can solve it with a new question. Of course, I think it can be helpful to give him relevant information, but as I said above, it doesn't have to be comprehensive. I think there are advantages to providing information, but there are also disadvantages. I think that by providing him with rather fragmented information, i can help even more.

Answer (score 1):

From the [test network documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html), "The deployCC subcommand will install the asset-transfer (basic) chaincode on peer0.org1.example.com and peer0.org2.example.com and then deploy the chaincode on the channel specified using the channel flag (or mychannel if no channel is specified)."

You should still be able to deploy your chaincode but you'll need to use the Fabric peer command directly instead of the test network scripts. The process is described in the [Deploying a smart contract to a channel tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploy_chaincode.html) and there is more detail in the [Fabric chaincode lifecycle documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode_lifecycle.html).